# Codeigniter change post variable

Tags: codeigniter, post

Im sending a post form on codeigniter, but when I receive it change the string.
The string is:  %1001200040010_ 
it cames from a plastic card.
And the echo shows: 01200040010_
I have tried with php without codeigniter and works fine. 
Could you help me?

Te form is

```
<div id="cl-wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid" id="pcont">
    <div class="cl-mcont">
    <form action="testpost" method="post">
    <p><strong>Introduzca el Nro. de tarjeta del socio:</strong><?php echo validation_errors(); ?><br />
    <input name="socio" maxlength="20" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off"/>
    </p>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" /></div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

the php

```
    function testpost()
{
    echo utf8_decode($_POST['socio']);
    exit();

}
```

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: have to tried without utf8 decode??

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.
I receive the variable post with $_REQUEST instead $_POST. Like this:

```
utf8_decode($_REQUEST['variable']) ;
```

Thanks...